# How to open an .rdl file in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, reporting

I have an .rdl file that I need to open in Visual Studio. When I try to open this file, I got an XML file. However, I am unable to see the designer format.

I don't know which version of Visual Studio is used to create this .rdl file.

Is it possible to open a random .rdl file in Visual Studio and see the designer format and, if so, how can I do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Correct, the Report Definition Language is just XML. And, as with any other file, you can just open it (File/Open/File...) in Visual Studio, just like in a text editor. In order to see a designer you need to give Visual Studio a bit of context about what sort of file it is by making it part of a Report Server Project.

- Install [SSDT for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) if you haven't already done so
- Create a new project using the 'Report Server Project' template
- Copy/move the .rdl file(s) you have into the folder for the newly created project (eg ..\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\My Report Project\My Report Project)
- Use the "Add Existing Item..." context menu option in Solution Explorer to add the .rdl to the project
- Open report designer by double-clicking the newly added report project item(s)

Comment: for me SSDT is unable to install.i am using visual studio 2012 version.

Comment: Is that that the full VS2012 or the shell that is installed by earlier versions of SQL Server?

Comment: It is FULL VS2012

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2008 r2 enterprise edition and also i have SQL server 2008 r2 express edition

Comment: Assuming you can't upgrade you'll need to use the shell version of VS that is bundled with 2008R2 Enterprise known as "Business Intelligence Development Studio". If you haven't already installed that (check in the SQL Server 2008 R2 start menu folder) rerun the SQL Server Installation Centre and then add features to your existing installation. After that its a matter of following the steps from "create a new project" as described in my original answer (I'll update that when I get a longer break)

Comment: Great! Since you are a student, you might want to consider upgrading your own software. Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition is totally free, and SQL Sever 2016 Developer Edition (ie all features) is free for use in a non-production environment. SSRS in particular has had a major overhaul

Comment: i didn't get the link for downloading SQL server 2016 Developer Edition. Can you help me to find the link?

Comment: Head over to [www.visualstudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/) and login/sign up. Then go to Downloads and you should see it

Comment: NOTE: For `Visual Studio 2019`, please download the extension of `Microsoft Reporting Services Projects` and `Microsoft RDLC Report Designer` to create a new project of `Report Server Project`.

Answer (score 5):

For opening RDL file in designer make sure you have "
Microsoft Reporting Services Projects" Installed.

Refer this : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the needed extensions (Microsoft Reporting Services, Report Designer) installed and everything updated, what worked for me was to open the .rptproj project, and then open the needed .rdl.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was opening the folder and not the project file.

Once I opened the project directly, the reports were opening with the report editor, not the xml editor.