# Editing RDL Files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

So we have a unique situation. I have 2300+ RDLs that we have in TFS that our team works on. These are deployed to 100+ different folders on the SSRS Server, and must stay that way as each folder is secured with it's own AD Group so users can't see each others folders/reports.

The problem with Visual Studio is that each folder has to be it's own project to manage the RDLs in Visual Studio. So my workaround is that I have a project in VS but then made my own folder with all of these RDL's and their own subfolder via Source Code Explorer. So when I try to edit the rdl with Visual studio it just opens it as xml and not the report designer. My work-around is that we associate the .rdl file with Report Builder, but I'd rather just use Visual Studio.

Any way to get VS to open the report designer this way? I am only interested in editing the rdl's this way, not using VS To deploy the reports.

Comment: Forgot to mention, we are using VS2017 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could try VS extension Microsoft Reporting Services Projects, which can be downloaded from website below:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio

Or try the solution in case [How to open .rdl file in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084161/how-to-open-rdl-file-in-visual-studio) :

> In order to see a designer you need to give Visual Studio a bit of
> context about what sort of file it is by making it part of a Report
> Server Project.
>
> - Install [SSDT for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) if you haven't already done so
> - Create a new project using the 'Report Server Project' template
> - Copy/move the .rdl file(s) you have into the folder for the newly created project (eg ..\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\My Report
>   Project\My Report Project)
> - Use the "Add Existing Item..." context menu option in Solution Explorer to add the .rdl to the project
> - Open report designer by double-clicking the newly added report project item(s)

Comment: I already have ssdt installed, I will look at the extension referenced. I can’t do as you say and add existing items. My question covered that, I have 100+ folders and ssdt does not allow for sub folders; which is ridiculous.

Comment: Have you checked the extension? Is it working for you?

Comment: I have that extension installed, and always have. It's not anything new to me. The issue is I can't have all 2000+ reports in one folder in one project.

Comment: Have you also checked `Microsoft Reporting Services Projects` extension?

Comment: Yea I have ssdt and the extension installed.